# How to commit different files to two distinct SVN (or git) repositories?

Tags: git, svn, repository

I have this project structure:

```
directoryA/
directoryB/
```

I need to commit `directoryA` to one repository, and `directoryA + directoryB` to a different repository, using SVN now, and Git in a few months time.

Which is the best strategy to commit different files to two different repositories, possibly with a single script?

Is it possible to keep two repositories open at the same time?

The operating system is Windows 10, but I would not mind if it could run on Linux, too.

Answer (score 1):

Use svn2git. You can use paths specify which repo.

https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git

```
create repository project_v1
end repository

create repository project_v2
end repository

match /trunk/project_v1/
repository project_v1
branch master
end match

match /trunk/project_v2/
repository project_v2
branch master
end match
```

Note: tags are branches in SVN and must be declared a little different. `([^/]+)/` is used to match tag name.

```
match /tags/project_v1/([^/]+)/
repository project_v1
branch refs/tags/\1
annotated=true
end match
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However my problems is not to convert a repository from SVN to git, yet. I have to make and work on two SVN repositories simultaneously (and do the same when moving to git in the future).